# Adding fuzziness to an ElasticSearch prefix query

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-cloud

I have two documents:

`{id: 1, name: "james"}`

`{id: 2, name: "james kennedy"}`

I am using the `match_bool_prefix` API for autocomplete, and I would like to be able to match the document with `id: 1` even if I incorrectly spell `james`.

Query: `jamis`

Desired output: finding document with `id: 1`.

Comment: It's weird to use `match_bool_prefix` for autocomplete since it can match terms in any positions, why not using `match_phrase_prefix` instead?

Comment: that is true, but it seemed like `match_phrase_prefix` didn't support fuzzy matching?